# How to handle click event from a Fragment, produces error Nullpointer exception, trying to invoke *setOnClickListener* from a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Please, i have been trying to handle click event from my project and haven't actually found a place to actually put the *button.setOnClickListener(handler);* statement. The truth is that i have a **ViewPager** inside another layout.xml file which i inflated from within a **Fragment**. But i have two other layout files, which i used to provide content for the **ViewPager** itself, which i did and it worked properly. But when i tried to handle *onClick* event from within any of my classes, it produces a *NullPointer Exception*. This is my first project on Android and i can't seem to find any solution even on StackOverflow, because none of the answers really solved my problem. I will really appreciate if someone could read through this long code and provide an answer to my problem. Thanks in advance. It's a Calculator App

**Code below**

```
    *In MainActivity.java*



        package com.projects.calculatorapp2;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
           super.onCreate(savedState);
           getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .beginTransaction()
                   .add(android.R.id.content, new ViewPagerFragment())
                   .commit();

       }
    }




    *In ViewPagerFragment.java*

    package com.projects.calculatorapp2;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    /**
     * <b><p>Description</p></b>
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass that provides view for the main activity.
     * @author Noah
     * @since 2020
     *
     */
    public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


        EditText input;
        protected ViewPager pager;
        public StringBuilder builderText = new StringBuilder();




        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
            super.onCreate(state);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
            pager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            input = view.findViewById(R.id.edit);


            pager.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
            return (view);

        }

     @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedState){
        Button one = view.findViewById(R.id.seven);
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int buttonId = view.getId();

            switch (buttonId) {

                case R.id.one: {
                    builderText.append(1);
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.valueOf(builderText));
                    input.setText(builderText);
                }
            }
        }




        private class ButtonAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            // default constructor chained to superclass
            ButtonAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2; //number of pages
            }


            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.valueOf(position));
                return (ButtonSet.newInstance(position));
            }
        }
    }






     *In ButtonSet.java*


        package com.projects.calculatorapp2;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;

        public class ButtonSet extends Fragment {

            public static final String POS_KEY = "position";



            static ButtonSet newInstance(int pos){

                ButtonSet bs = new ButtonSet();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt(POS_KEY, pos);
                bs.setArguments(bundle);
                return (bs);
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                     ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle state) {

                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                if(getArguments().getInt(POS_KEY) == 0)
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_1,
                            container, false);

                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_2,
                        container, false);

            }



        }






     *In activity_main.xml* (Main layout file when app is lauched)

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@id/edit"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor"
                android:hint="@string/ediText_hint"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|end"

                />

          <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
              <Button
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                  android:layout_marginEnd="110dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                  android:background="@color/black"
                  android:clickable="false" />

              <Button
                  android:id="@id/c_button"
                  android:layout_width="100dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:text="@string/delete"
                  android:background="@color/dark_red"/>

          </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>

*In content_1.xml* (This is first content of ViewPager)

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context="com.projects.calculatorapp2.ViewPagerFragment">


        <!-- First button representing 7 -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/seven"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/seven"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="25"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/eight"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/eight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/four"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- Second button representing 8 -->
            <Button
                android:id="@id/eight"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/nine"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/five"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:text="@string/eight"/>

        <!-- Third button representing 9 -->
            <Button
                android:id="@id/nine"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/divide"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/six"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:text="@string/nine"/>

        <!-- Fourth button representing division sign (/) -->
            <Button
                android:id="@id/divide"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/times"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:text="@string/divide" />


        <!-- Fifth button representing 4 -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/four"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/seven"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/one"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/four" />


        <!-- Sixth button representing 5 -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/five"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/eight"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/four"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/two"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/five" />


        <!-- Seventh button representing 6 -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/six"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nine"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/five"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/three"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/six" />

        <!-- Eight button representing multiplication sign (x) -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/times"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divide"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/six"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/minus"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:text="@string/times" />

        <!-- Eighth button representing 1 -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"

            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/four"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/decimal"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/one" />


        <!-- Ninth button representing 2 -->

        <Button
            android:id="@id/two"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/five"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/zero"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/two" />

        <!-- Tenth button representing 3 -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/three"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/times"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/two"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/equals"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/three" />


        <!-- Eleventh button representing subtration sign ( - ) -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/minus"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/times"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/three"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/add"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/minus" />

        <!-- Twelfth button representing decimal point ( . ) -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/decimal"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/decimal" />


        <!-- Thirteenth button representing zero ( 0 )-->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/zero"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/two"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/decimal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/zero" />


        <!-- Fourteenth button representing equals sign ( = ) -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/equals"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/three"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/zero"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/equals" />

        <!-- Fifteenth button representing addition sign ( + ) -->
        <Button
            android:id="@id/add"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minus"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="@string/add" />




    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>




*In content_2.xml* (Second content of ViewPager)


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <Button
            android:id="@id/sin"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/sin"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/log"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/cos"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/cos"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tan"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/log10"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/tan"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/tan"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/factorial"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"/>



        <Button
            android:id="@id/log"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/log"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pi"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sin"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/log10"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/log10"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cos"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/log"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tan"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/factorial"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/factorial"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tan"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pow"/>



        <Button
            android:id="@id/pi"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/pi"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/log"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/exp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/exp"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/log10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pi"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tan"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/pow"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/pow"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/factorial"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Log message*

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.projects.calculatorapp2.ViewPagerFragment.onViewCreated(ViewPagerFragment.java:57)

Comment: Why is `ViewPagerFragment` inflating `activity_main`?

Comment: Also after process death, you will have overlapping `ViewPagerFragment`s. Do you want to have N fragments on top of each other?

Comment: activity_main was Android studio's auto-generated xml file, i forgot to change the name

Comment: I also know about the overlapping, but i do not want that. I just haven't handled that error yet. The onClick() error is what i want to address first

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onViewCreated()` in your fragment and you can set your click listeners in that method.

Also I see an issue in your ids. It should be like

```
android:id="@+id/seven"
```

Notice the + sign

**Detailed**
Make your fragment having the button implement `View.OnClickListener`

Then override the `onViewCreated` method. Inside it do something like this for every button:

```
yourButton = view.findViewById(R.id.seven);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Do the same for all buttons

Edit:
Override the onViewCreated method in your `ButtonSet` fragment and also put a position check like this:

```
//inside onViewCreated
if(position == 0) {
    //init buttons from content 1 xml layout, and set listeners
} else {
    //init buttons from content 2 layout
}
```

Comment: It still produced the same error even after adding the + sign in id attribute, and overriding onViewCreated()

Comment: You should also make sure you are initialising your view correctly based on the position. Like if position is 0,only initialise buttons from your first layout and if it's 1 then from your second layout

Comment: You can put a check in your OnViewCreated method if position is 0 init your first layout buttons and same for position 1

Comment: @artenson.art89, i have added the Log message to the question

Comment: Override the onViewCreated in your button Set fragment not the viewpager fragment

Comment: Ok, i'll try that now.